# Sphinx: WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo

Tags: database, sphinx

I'm new to Sphinx and I can't seem to figure out what this warning is referring to or how to fix it. A google search didn't provide much information so I'm hoping a database guru here knows how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing to be scared. The message says that the mode of additional attributes storing, which is set in the config file, will be turned off, due to absence of these attributes.

`docinfo` is the complete set of per-document attribute values.

Read more about this here http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/attributes.html

Comment: So how to get rid of this warning? I don't need to specify attributes. But every time my cron starts the indexer, it throws this warning. How to suppress it?

Comment: @ChristopherK. As far as I know there is no way to suppress it.

Comment: @ChristopherK. You can put `docinfo = none` in the index configuration block to remove this warning.