# Sphinx search by path of a word

Tags: sphinx

I have simple table

```
id: primary
name: varchar fulltext index
```

here is my Sphinx config
https://justpaste.it/1okop

Indexer warns about docinfo

> Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6) Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew
>   Aksyonoff Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc
>   (http://sphinxsearch.com)
>
> using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'... indexing index
>   'words'... WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
>   collected 10000 docs, 0.1 MB sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done total 10000
>   docs, 79566 bytes total 0.065 sec, 1210829 bytes/sec, 152179.20
>   docs/sec total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 94.6 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
>   total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 47.5 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

But it's said here [Sphinx: WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664813/sphinx-warning-attribute-count-is-0-switching-to-none-docinfo) that it's nothing seriouse.

OK, starting service and search for part of the word:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_words
where match (name) AGAINST ('lema')
No rows.

Tha same as
SELECT *
FROM test_words
where match (name) AGAINST ('*lema*')
```

No rows.

And in the same time there are results for query

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_words`
where position('lema' in name)>0
```

so as far as I can see - Sphinx is not searching by part of a word.
Why and how to fix it?

And - if I uncomment

```
min_infix_len = 3 
infix_fields = name
```

I get

```
WARNING: index 'words': prefix_fields and infix_fields has no effect with dict=keywords, ignoring
```

And one more - **show engines;** show no Sphinx engine, is it normal now? mysql service was restarted.

All sql queries were run through Adminer logged in localhost:3312

Answer (score 0):

There's no functions like position() or syntax like 'match(name) against' in Sphinx. According to your config your index is 'words' while your requests are against 'test_words' which is the source table you build your index from. So it seems to me you're connecting not to Sphinx, but to mysql. If you're looking for closer integration between MySQL and Sphinx try SphinxSE (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/devel.html#sphinxse), it will then show up in "SHOW ENGINES" or if you don't want to deal with compiling MySQL with SphinxSE enable you might want to try Manticore Search (a fork of Sphinx) since it has integration with FEDERATED engine (https://docs.manticoresearch.com/2.6.4/html/federated_storage_engine.html) which is by default compiled in mysql, you just need to start it properly to enable it.

If you want to use Sphinx traditional way just make sure you connect to it, not to MySQL.

Comment: I guess I connect to Sphinx, see screenshot https://yadi.sk/i/UCqxbjrZiW2BMA and the reason why there's no Sphinx engine is that probably I've missed something. I run indexer, restarted sphinxsearch & mysql services, something else?..

Comment: Opps, should I recompile mysql?!

Comment: Your screenshot suggests you NOT **really** connected to sphinx/searchd! Firstly you have `listen = 3312` in config, means searchd is listing within SphixnAPI on that port - NOT SphinxQL (mysql protocol)! need `listen 9306:mysql41` or similar. And your mysql client MIGHT ignore the specified port, if finding a mysql socket, to bypass TCP connection. Try using 127.0.0.1 rather than 'localhost' - as the TCP bypass typically is hardcoded to work with 'localhost' explicitly)

Comment: Yes, it working, thanks! 9306:mysql41 and login to 127.0.0.1:9306. If you write answer I'll mark it as solution )

Answer (score 0):

In sphinx it calls extended-syntax, you should specify field by @field, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test_words
WHERE match('@name lema')
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.